# How does Git change the shell prompt in Aptana Studio's Cygwin Terminal?

Tags: shell, git, prompt

I'm running Aptana studio 3.3.2. The command echo `$SHELL` outputs `/bin/sh`.
However there is no value for the `PS1` environment variable which I would
like to inspect. I cannot there is no `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file but
I would like to inspect `PS1` environment variable.

This because in Git, when I do a

```
git init myproject
cd myproject
```

I get the following prompt

> `foo/myproject (master)`

I cannot figure out how the shell manages to append the (master) string
to the directory name found in `PS1`. After all the directory name is myproject,
not "`myproject (master)`".

Thanks.

As an update, here is my shell:

```
Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.1.0(3)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

and here is a printout of my environment variables:

```
Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$ pwd
/c/Users/Neil

Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$ env
HOMEPATH=\Users\Neil
APPDATA=C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Roaming
PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files
TERM=cygwin
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
WINDIR=C:\Windows
COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData
USERDOMAIN=NEIL-PC
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
OS=Windows_NT
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
!::=::\
TEMP=/tmp
COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPNAME=AdobeDrive
USERNAME=Neil
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PATH=/c/Users/Neil/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3/jre/bin/client:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Lo
cal/Aptana Studio 3/jre/bin:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3/jre/lib/i386:/c/glassfish3/jdk7/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73:/c/Pr
ogram Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Co
rporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Sony/VA
IO Startup Setting Tool:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Micr
osoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/
100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsof
t SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/:/c/Program Files (x86)
/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/Pr
ogram Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies
/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/glassfish3/jdk7/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/
vim73:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86
)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x
86)/Sony/VAIO Startup Setting Tool:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Program
 Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x8
6)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/:/c/Program
Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/
Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/Privat
eAssemblies/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/Users/Neil/Desktop/adt-bundle-window
s-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools:/c/Users/Neil/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio
3:.
PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
PWD=/c/Users/Neil
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
JAVA_HOME=C:\glassfish3\jdk7
VS120COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Neil
LANG=IT
APTANA_VERSION=3.3.2.1358388697
CM2015DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\
LOGONSERVER=\\NEIL-PC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Local
!C:=C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress392
HOME=/c/Users/Neil
SHLVL=1
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
HOMEDRIVE=C:
WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS=3
WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
MSYSTEM=MINGW32
PROMPT=$P$G
COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
LESS=-FRSX
LOGNAME=Neil
TMP=/tmp
SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2a07
CONFIGSETROOT=C:\Windows\ConfigSetRoot
MAKE_MODE=unix
PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files (x86)
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPVERSION=1.0.0
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPLOCALE=it_IT
PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
SESSIONNAME=Console
GNUPGHOME=/c/Users/Neil/.gnupg
HISTFILE=/c/Users/Neil/.bash_history
COMPUTERNAME=NEIL-PC
OLDPWD=/c/xampp/htdocs/wordpress392
_=/bin/env

Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$ set
!::='::\'
!C:='C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress392'
ALLUSERSPROFILE='C:\ProgramData'
APPDATA='C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Roaming'
APTANA_VERSION=3.3.2.1358388697
BASH=/usr/bin/sh
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="3" [1]="1" [2]="0" [3]="3" [4]="release" [5]="i686-pc-msys")
BASH_VERSION='3.1.0(3)-release'
CM2015DIR='C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\Materials\'
COLUMNS=153
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPLOCALE=it_IT
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPNAME=AdobeDrive
COM.ADOBE.VERSIONCUE.CLIENT.APPVERSION=1.0.0
COMMONPROGRAMFILES='C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)='C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432='C:\Program Files\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME=NEIL-PC
COMP_WORDBREAKS='
"'\''@><=;|&(:'
COMSPEC='C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe'
CONFIGSETROOT='C:\Windows\ConfigSetRoot'
DIRSTACK=()
EUID=500
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
GNUPGHOME=/c/Users/Neil/.gnupg
GROUPS=()
HISTFILE=/c/Users/Neil/.bash_history
HISTFILESIZE=500
HISTSIZE=500
HOME=/c/Users/Neil
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH='\Users\Neil'
HOSTNAME=NEIL-PC
HOSTTYPE=i686
IFS='
'
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
JAVA_HOME='C:\glassfish3\jdk7'
LANG=IT
LESS=-FRSX
LINES=44
LOCALAPPDATA='C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Local'
LOGNAME=Neil
LOGONSERVER='\\NEIL-PC'
MACHTYPE=i686-pc-msys
MAILCHECK=60
MAKE_MODE=unix
MSYSTEM=MINGW32
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OLDPWD=/c/xampp/htdocs/wordpress392
OPTERR=1
OPTIND=1
OS=Windows_NT
OSTYPE=msys
PATH='/c/Users/Neil/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3/jre/bin/client:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/L
ocal/Aptana Studio 3/jre/bin:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3/jre/lib/i386:/c/glassfish3/jdk7/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73:/c/P
rogram Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA C
orporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Sony/V
AIO Startup Setting Tool:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/Mic
rosoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server
/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microso
ft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/:/c/Program Files (x86
)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/P
rogram Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblie
s/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/glassfish3/jdk7/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/Vim
/vim73:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/Windows Live:/c/Program Files (x8
6)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files (
x86)/Sony/VAIO Startup Setting Tool:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft ASP.NET/ASP.NET Web Pages/v1.0/:/c/Progra
m Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/HashiCorp/Vagrant/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft
 SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x
86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/Tools/Binn/VSShell/Common7/IDE/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/:/c/Program
 Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/100/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS
/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/Priva
teAssemblies/:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn/:/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/Users/Neil/Desktop/adt-bundle-windo
ws-x86_64-20130219/sdk/tools:/c/Users/Neil/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platform-tools:/c/Users/NeilZanella/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio
 3:.'
PATHEXT='.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC'
PIPESTATUS=([0]="0")
PLINK_PROTOCOL=ssh
POSIXLY_CORRECT=y
PPID=1
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER='Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=2a07
PROGRAMDATA='C:\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES='C:\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMFILES(X86)='C:\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432='C:\Program Files'
PROMPT='$P$G'
PS1='\[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007
\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[33m\w$(__git_ps1)\033[0m\]
$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PSMODULEPATH='C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\'
PUBLIC='C:\Users\Public'
PWD=/c/Users/Neil
SESSIONNAME=Console
SHELL=/bin/sh
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:posix
SHLVL=1
SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
SYSTEMROOT='C:\Windows'
TEMP=/tmp
TERM=cygwin
TMP=/tmp
UID=500
USERDOMAIN=NEIL-PC
USERNAME=Neil
USERPROFILE='C:\Users\Neil'
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH='C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\'
VS110COMNTOOLS='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\'
VS120COMNTOOLS='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\'
WINDIR='C:\Windows'
WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS=3
WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE='C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log'
_=env
__git_all_commands=
__git_diff_common_options='--stat --numstat --shortstat --summary
                        --patch-with-stat --name-only --name-status --color
                        --no-color --color-words --no-renames --check
                        --full-index --binary --abbrev --diff-filter=
                        --find-copies-harder
                        --text --ignore-space-at-eol --ignore-space-change
                        --ignore-all-space --exit-code --quiet --ext-diff
                        --no-ext-diff
                        --no-prefix --src-prefix= --dst-prefix=
                        --inter-hunk-context=
                        --patience
                        --raw
                        --dirstat --dirstat= --dirstat-by-file
                        --dirstat-by-file= --cumulative
'
__git_fetch_options='
        --quiet --verbose --append --upload-pack --force --keep --depth=
        --tags --no-tags --all --prune --dry-run
'
__git_log_common_options='
        --not --all
        --branches --tags --remotes
        --first-parent --merges --no-merges
        --max-count=
        --max-age= --since= --after=
        --min-age= --until= --before=
'
__git_log_date_formats='relative iso8601 rfc2822 short local default raw'
__git_log_gitk_options='
        --dense --sparse --full-history
        --simplify-merges --simplify-by-decoration
        --left-right
'
__git_log_pretty_formats='oneline short medium full fuller email raw format:'
__git_log_shortlog_options='
        --author= --committer= --grep=
        --all-match
'
__git_merge_options='
        --no-commit --no-stat --log --no-log --squash --strategy
        --commit --stat --no-squash --ff --no-ff --ff-only
'
__git_merge_strategies=
__git_mergetools_common='diffuse ecmerge emerge kdiff3 meld opendiff
                        tkdiff vimdiff gvimdiff xxdiff araxis p4merge
'
__git_porcelain_commands=
__git_send_email_confirm_options='always never auto cc compose'
__git_send_email_suppresscc_options='author self cc bodycc sob cccmd body all'
__git_whitespacelist='nowarn warn error error-all fix'
i='/etc/profile.d/*.sh'

Neil@NEIL-PC ~
$
```

The variables of interest seem to be:

PROMPT=$P$G

PS1='[\033]0;$MSYSTEM:\w\007
\033[32m]\u@\h [\033[33m\w$(__git_ps1)\033[0m]
$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '

Can someone explain how these variables interact? What is $G and $(__git_ps1) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Aptana Studio specifically, but there are various mechanisms that can influence the shell prompt. I assume you're using Bash as you mentioned `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

The simplest mechanism is to set the `PS1` variable (supported by most shells, even straight POSIX ones like `dash`), which doesn't necessarily need to be an environment variable. There are various escape sequences you can put in it to print information as part of the prompt. To inspect `PS1`, simply run the following:

```
echo $PS1
```

However, I don't know of any sequences that, by themselves, can be used to print the current Git branch (`master`).

There is also a `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable that specifies a function to run before the prompt is displayed; this function can be used to generate an arbitrary prompt. Here's an example implementation of the behavior you describe:

```bash
foobar() {
    local branch
    branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*') || branch='?'
    branch=${branch##* }
    # \w: current working directory
    PS1="\\w ($branch) "
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=foobar
```

There are a number of files that Bash will read at startup:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- `~/.profile`
- any file specified using `--rcfile`

Any of these might be responsible for setting the prompt. Aptana Studio probably provides a custom startup file.

You can find out more about prompting in the "Prompting" section of the [Bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

#### Update

In the `PS1` value that you provided, `$(__git_ps1)` is a substitution (per standard Bash command substitution syntax, but expanded when used rather than when defined) that will be expanded to the output of the `__git_ps1` command. You can find out what that is like so:

```
type -a __git_ps1
```

If it's a function or alias, its definition will be printed. If it's an executable, its path will be shown.